# C# - Save Settings

Tags: c#, save, settings

I use a boolean value in a Settings file.

I make changes in its value during runtime and then save the changes:

```
svn_util_Settings.Default["EnableChangingDiagramProperties"] = true;
svn_util_Settings.Default.Save();
```

I get the following error, and the settings are not saved:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version 4.0.0.0'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your target framework?

Comment: @HassanNisar, .Net 3.5, Can I use Settings file in that framework?

Comment: Yes you can, look into setting designer in Properties section of Solution Explorer.

Comment: @HassanNisar, What should I check there?

Comment: Set the scope of each settings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58594/discussion-between-hassan-nisar-and-user3165438).